# In a grid slider, how to add a delay between each slide?

Tags: jquery, grid, slider, delay, intervals

here is my situation,

I have a "grid slider", make understand I have a grid of 2 columns, 3 rows.

Each box has a different content.

I woud like each of those boxe to slide, with a different interval.

Example boxe A slider after 5 secs, B after 7, C after 9, d after 11. Adding 2 seconds delay for each box.

So far I've been using this plugin:

http://onether.com/grid-slider/examples/testimonials-slider-custom-arrows-position-offset

But it make slide the all slides together:

Here is my live example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BzybNW

I' calling the js like:

```
$(function ()
{
$('.comp-quotes-1').gridSlider({
    cols: 2, //Column count. Degrades on smaller screens. Degradation steps can be easily adjusted in css.
    rows: 3, //Row count. Applies to sliders only.
    col_spacing_size: 5, //Spacing that occurs between grid cells.
    transition: 'slideLeft', //)
    scroll_speed: 1000, //Scroll speed in miliseconds
    ctrl_always_visible: true, //Slider controls visible at all times or on hover only
    ctrl_arrows_pos_y: 'top', //Vertical position of slider arrows
    ctrl_arrows_pos_x: 'right', //Horizontal position of slider arrows
    ctrl_arrows_pos_shift_y: -76, //Custom vertical offset of slider arrows
    ctrl_pag_pos_y: 'bottom', //Vertical position of slider pag
    ctrl_pag_pos_x: 'right', //Horizontal position of slider pag
    ctrl_pag_pos_shift_y: 70, //Custom vertical offset of slider pag
    ctrl_style: 10, //Style of navigation (for custom one provide path to filename)
    ctrl_arrows_spacing: 2, //Minimum spacing between arrows
    autoplay_enable: true, //Autoplay
    autoplay_interval: 2, //Autoplay interval in seconds
    ctrl_pag_spacing: 2, //Minimum spacing between pagination items
    ctrl_pag: false,
    scroll_on_mousewheel: false,
});
```

If you have any tips how this could be achieve, it will be awesome !!

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: You can do it but for that you would need to  make some changes in plugin code. **URL:** http://onether.com/wp-content/gridslider/gridslider.js, **function**: egs.resume_autoplay, **change set timeout value to**: _(cfg.view_pos+1) * 2 * 1000_

Comment: sorry, change it to: **(2 * cfg.view_pos+5) * 1000**